# Publishing internet facing site on SharePoint 2010 Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, publishing

I've had follow the documentation to setup a Publishing internet face site. After setting on the site and editing a page an error occurr:

My steps:

Setup a publishing site under a domain authoring.test.local and a public url public.test.local, I set my account as site collection administrator.

Publishing Portal was the site template selected

1. Access the authoring.test.local edit Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Features:

SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure : Active

1. Site Actions -> Site Settings - Site Actions -> Site Manage Features:

SharePoint Server Publishing: Active

So, for my understanding that's all that need to be done in order to publish the site: After editing a page and click Public submit, i get the following error:

"The following location is not accesible, because it's in a different site collation:
http://authoring.test.local/_catalogs/wfpub/Publishing Approval/reviewpublishing_1033.xsn":

My account has approval permission

Could anybody provide a hint ?

Thx;

Answer (score 0):

Is the Publishing Approval Workflow feature in Site collection features also activated?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a WCM reference implmentation on my blog. See if it helps you.
http://markviky.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-web-content-management.html